# Mule method cannot be cast to string

Tags: mule, mule-studio

i'm very new to mule studio.

This is the environements setup.

**VM1** = Windows 7, Visual Studio 2012, IIS 7.
A .net 4.5 WCF webservice hosted in IIS7 that has an operation that accepts a string and returns a string.

**VM2** = Ubuntu 13.4 OpenJDK 1.7.0_25 Mule Studio 3.5 Community Edition.

I created a JAXWS-Client with an outbound endpoint, I did this by clicking the generate from WSDL and entering the url of the .net WCF webservice hosted in IIS on **VM1**. That was fine.

I then created an inbound endpoint with a jaxws-Service in-between the inbound service and the outbound client there is a logger and an object to string.

If I setup a vanilla inbound endpoint (no soap) and use a simple html form to post it all works fine and I get a string back to the browser. But adding the Soap Component causes the dispatcherexception when the flow hits the Soap Component just prior to the outbound endpoint.

> org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException: java.lang.reflect.Method
>   cannot be cast to java.lang.String. Failed to route event via
>   endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message
>   payload is of type: String

```
 <flow name="testtwoFlow1" doc:name="testtwoFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"   path="SimplePing" doc:name="HTTP" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081"/>

    <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="TestTwo.IPing" doc:name="SOAP" />

    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <flow-ref name="testtwoFlow3" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>

</flow>
<sub-flow name="testtwoFlow3" doc:name="testtwoFlow3">

    <cxf:jaxws-client operation="SimplePing" serviceClass="TestTwo.IPing" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP"/>

    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="192.168.0.2" port="80" path="MuleExperiments/Ping.svc" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" />
</sub-flow>
```

I Have googled extensively and I haven been much in the way if examples that show an inbound service interacting with an outbound client. Or descriptions of the exception thrown, what causes it and how to address it. I'm guessing pretty much its because the service and the client are generated from the same WSDL, but I wouldn't have thought that would be a real issue. Or that in my cxf:jaxws-service & cxf:jaxws-service the service class is the same.

What my goal is, at this juncture, is to have a simple in/out of a string

Comment: Sorry Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056704/how-to-consume-a-soap-web-service-in-a-mule-flow

Comment: My client was wrongly configured it should have been clientClass not serviceClass and the port needed to be set as well. <cxf:jaxws-client operation="SimplePing"  enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" doc:name="SOAP" clientClass="TestTwo.PingService" port="BasicHttpBinding_IPing"/>

Comment: Is it working? If yes, post an answer and accept it, so the question doesn't remain open for ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My client was wrongly configured. It should have been clientClass, not serviceClass, and the port needed to be set as well. Once I made these changes, I got it working.

```
<cxf:jaxws-client
   operation="SimplePing"
   enableMuleSoapHeaders="true"
   doc:name="SOAP"
   clientClass="TestTwo.PingService"
   port="BasicHttpBinding_IPing"
/>
```