# mule java.lang.reflect.Method cannot be cast to java.lang.String (java.lang.ClassCastException)

Tags: mule

We are getting an error while using proxy client to send an XML to a web service. Here is the configuration:

```
<flow name="CreateDIMEntry" doc:name="CreateDIMEntry">
    <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="DIM_VM" doc:name="VM"/>
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" xsl-file="D:\Users\vkamat\Desktop\dim\src\main\resources\addenvelopetopayload.xsl" doc:name="XSLT"/>
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <logger message="I am here..#[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <set-property propertyName="SOAPAction" value="urn:com.org.ProcessActivity" doc:name="Property"/>

    <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/soap+xml" doc:name="Property"/>
    <!--  <set-property propertyName="SOAPAction" value="urn:com.org.ProcessActivity" doc:name="Property"/> -->
    <cxf:proxy-client doc:name="SOAP" payload="envelope">

    </cxf:proxy-client >

    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${dim.host}" port="${dim.port}" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" path="${dim.path}">
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

when called this flow with testing flow as below, it works fine

```
<flow name="DimFlow1" doc:name="DimFlow1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="D:\Documents\test" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <flow-ref name="CreateDIMEntry" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
</flow>
```

But when integrated in another flow, it gives an error, Giving snippet of main flow from where it is getting called

```
<async doc:name="Async">
    <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
    <mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" xsl-file="D:\addenvelopetopayload.xsl" doc:name="XSLT"/>

    <logger message="before DIM-- #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <flow-ref name="CreateDIMEntry" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
</async>
```

The error encountered is

```
********************************************************************************
Message               : java.lang.reflect.Method cannot be cast to java.lang.String. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: ReversibleXMLStreamReader
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. java.lang.reflect.Method cannot be cast to java.lang.String (java.lang.ClassCastException)
  org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor:338 (null)
2. java.lang.reflect.Method cannot be cast to java.lang.String. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: ReversibleXMLStreamReader (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor:150 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.reflect.Method cannot be cast to java.lang.String
  at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.getMethodOrOperationName(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:338)
  at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.getOperation(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:356)
  at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.doSendWithClient(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:212)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Are you sure that the payload going to `CreateDIMEntry` is of the same  type/format in both calling flows?

Comment: in working case, it is ReceiverFileInputStream while in the non-working case it is byte-array. Is it because the payload format is not matching?

Comment: You may need to experiment with more/different [transformation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Transformers).  I see this as the perfect scenario for a Mule functional test that will allow you to mess around with inputs and outputs to get it working.  Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297125/mule-method-cannot-be-cast-to-string) may not be exactly the same problem as yours but may offer some insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the following before the CXF client:

```
<set-variable value="#[flowVars['cxf_operation'].getLocalPart()]" variableName="operation" />
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it gave an error of no such operation. On better look, I noticed, the flow variable cxf_operation contained value that of the cxf operation from the main flow(code before async block). Simple removal of all flow variables (cxf_operation,method,cxf_service) solved the problem. Thanks for your help!!